# I see my old GitHub username when I run "ssh git@github.com"

Tags: git, ssh, github

I created a new GitHub account with new keypair and setup everything and can do anything without any problems at my other Mac but I cant clone my repo at this mac and I see my old username (gxlrygt) when I ssh. How can I change it to my new username ?

```
~ root# ssh git@github.com

PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
ERROR: Hi gxlrygt! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Comment: You're still using the old keypair

Comment: You should ask GitHub Support, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: you can answer your own question that details (a paragraph is all that is needed) what you did, and then you can select it as the answer in a couple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@will, sure man!
The problem was, I was using my old keypair, when I logged out from my os system and logged in again, the old keypair was removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this [Github: SSH issues](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/), it was helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *assuming* that you've already **created** new keys and **added** them into the [github's settings](https://github.com/settings/keys)

Then you just need to do something regarding your system's **ssh context**.

With the following commands you'll **clean** your ssh keys, **add them again** and **connect** with github's ssh server:

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add
ssh -T git@github
```

After that you'll probably see a message like this:

> Hi [YOUR NEW USER NAME]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.